# Transferring specific data from an old PS3 to a new one?

Tags: ps3, little-big-planet-2

Alright, so my old PS3 is broken, won't turn on at all, and if it does, immediately shuts off on it's own immediately after it turns on or a few minutes after which. That's all fine and good, because most of the data I have on there is stuff I can easily do again, or at least enjoy again. However, my main concern is for my Little Big Planet 2 data. I'm not playing through all of that again, because I don't need to. You see, I'm a composer and I used to use the music sequencer in LBP 2 to compose my music. But the PS3 broke, and I got a new one for Christmas.

Is there any way for me to be able to take the LBP 2 data from my old PS3 and put it in the new one? I want to be able to look at the notes of my songs and re-create them on FL Studio. It would be a great help if somebody would tell me how, if there is any way, so I don't have to re-make all of them by memory!

Comment: If your old PS3 doesn't stay on long enough to copy data, you may be out of luck. PS3 hard drives use an encrypted filesystem, so you can't read the data on the drive with anything other than the original system. If you published any of your levels, though, they should still be there as long as you sign in with the same SEN account.

Answer (score 0):

If you care enough for the data, you still could try to repair it (not necessarily personally of course) to state it could work for a hour or two. That could be enough to back up LBP2 data to external hard drive.

If you fail at repairing it you can do nothing about it, unfortunatelly.